# The Zero's '0' are getting removed automatically when i am converting my HTML template to excel sheets.

Tags: python, html, django, export-to-excel, xlrd

The whole process is that i am passing lists to the html template in Django as :-

```
def download_workbook(request):
    lists = family.objects.all()
    # your excel html format
    template_name = "sample_excel.html"

    response = render_to_response(template_name, {'lists': lists})
    # this is the output file
    filename = "sample.xls"

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-16'
    return response
```

My template is sample_excel.html:-

```
PERSONNEL_NUMBERR   DEPENDT_FIRST_NAME1     DEPENDT_FAMILY_NAME DEPENDANT_TYPE  DEPENDT_BIRTH_DATE  DEPENDANT_SEQUENCE  FAMILY_ID
{% autoescape off %} {% for list in lists %}{{ str(list.member.personal_number) }}  {{ list.dependent_first_name1 }}    {{ list.dependent_family_name }}    {{ list.dependent_type }}   {{ list.dependent_birthdate }}  {{ list.dependent_sequence }}   {{ str(list.family_uid) }}
{% endfor %}{% endautoescape %}
```

there are two of the fields in database, i.e., personal_number and family_uid whose sample data is as :-

```
personal_number 000029
family_uid 0000290001
```

But when the excel sheet is downloaded these number gets changed.

```
personal_number 29
family_uid 290001
```

Comment: I presume you are viewing this in excel. Does it look ok in a plain text editor? Excel will ignore the 0s at the beginning. You could make them a string to maintain the 0s.

Comment: Converting them to string did not work... I tried it !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using xlwt, it worked for me, i also faced the same problem. By using this u need not to have any html template, python itself will convert ur integer into string and write the resulting into excel sheet.
Follow this link.
http://djangotricks.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-export-data-as-excel.html

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a number gets treated as text and not as numerical data in Excel, place the number in a string and prepend an `'` apostrophe before writing to Excel. So instead of writing just `000029`, you would write `'000029`. In Excel this will display as `000029`. The apostrophe doesn't display; Excel just uses it as a flag indicating that this should be treated as text.

Alternatively, you could change the format of the cell to Text before writing to it, in which case you don't necessarily have to prepend a `'`. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that from Python.

Comment: Its working , but the problem is that its showing the apostrophe also in excel.